# Strange behavior of the informix procedure call

Tags: procedure, informix

I have been writing the procedure in SPL for Informix database. I have one big procedure which calls smaller procedures. I observed strange behavior when I inserted the return statement after the first call.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main( )
            RETURNING INTEGER, INTEGER, CHAR (200);

    call procedure1();
RETURN 0, 0, "OK";
    call procedure2();
    call procedure3();

END procedure;
```

When I compare running time with this variant:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main( )
            RETURNING INTEGER, INTEGER, CHAR (200);

    call procedure1();
END procedure;
```

The differences in running time {time required for execution of these two procedures} are striking. The first program runs ten times more than second.
Does anybody know, what does Informix doing and why there is so long waiting time for procedures that are not executed?

Comment: You can add the debug to check `set debug file to "/tmp/debug.out" ; trace on; ` , include this before the call

Comment: I'm surprised that semicolons aren't needed after the `CALL` statements.  The second version doesn't have a RETURN statement that returns the values that the function signature says it will return.  That may be a factor in the problem.  Consider timing a variant without the RETURNING clause and just the  single CALL.  Consider timing the first variant with the calls to `procedure2()` and `procedure3()` removed (that shouldn't affect the timing).

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, use of semicolons is compulsory in Informix. The code snippets above are only for illustration purpose. Informix does not report any error and also procedures works fine. I was only surprised why there is so much difference in execution time of these two variants of same  procedure. I wondered if there is some "preparation phase" before execution of procedure or something like that.

Comment: The first procedure always takes much more time than the second? If you execute the the first procedure several times, does it still take much more time than the secondo procedure? I did a very simple test on a local VM on my laptop and there were no significant differences in execution times. Then again, we do not know what your procedures are doing.